# How to get random item in a list, and get another random item from a second list with the name of the first choose

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I Have a list called `"Livros"`
in `"Livros"` i have `("Lucas", "Isaias").`

I have other two lists , one called "Lucas" and other called "Isaias"
in `Lucas` i have `("Lucas1", "Lucas2", "Lucas3")`
and in `Isaias` `("Isaias1", "Isaias2", "Isaias3")`

So, i need to choice a random one in `"Livros"` between both `"Lucas` and Isaias".
for example, if i choise `("Lucas")`
i will need to raffle one more item in Lucas list.

so, now for example, if my choise is `"Lucas2"`
ill need to raflle the last item in a `dict` called `"Lucas2"` that i have

```py
  Lucas2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4" 
}
```

and for last i need to print the key and value in the respective dict.

i tried a thing , but i get just one letter at second print.. so i cant search in dicts.. 
anyone can help me?

i've been lookin for answers in google, forums and etc... no successful

````py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import *

Livros = ["Lucas", "Isaias"]


Lucas = ["Lucas1", "Lucas2"]
Isaias = ["Isaias1", "Isaias2"]

Lucas1 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}

Lucas2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4" 
}

Isaias1 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}


Isaias2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}

x = choice(Livros)
print(x)

xx = choice(x)
print(xx)```
````

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you absolutely need the initial name lists to contain strings?

Comment: Could you not just use the respective lists themselves? Or convert them into dictionaries and nest them?

Comment: You can store it in a `dict` like this `Livros = {"Lucas": Lucas, "Isaias": Isaias}`.

Comment: dijksterhuis, ure right, i dont need to use strings in list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to print out the keys, then use nested dictionaries instead of lists. I’m sure there must be a fancy way to do the random choices at the end, recursively or something, but this works as required.

```
import random

Lucas1 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}

Lucas2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4" 
}

Lucas = {"Lucas1": Lucas1, "Lucas2": Lucas2}
Isaias = {"Isaias1": Isaias1, "Isaias2": Isaias2}

Livros = {"Lucas": Lucas, "Isaias": Isaias}

master_key = random.choice(Livros.keys())
entity_key = random.choice(Livros[master_key].keys())
result_key = random.choice(Livros[master_key][entity_key].keys())
print(result_key, Livros[master_key][entity_key][result_key])
```

Otherwise, just nest the objects inside the list:

```
Lucas1 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4"
}

Lucas2 = {
    "1" : "Text1" ,
    "2" : "Text2" ,
    "3" : "Text3" ,
    "4" : "Text4" 
}

Lucas = [Lucas1, Lucas2, ... ]
Livros = [Lucas, Isaias]

result = random.choice(random.choice(random.choice(Livros)))
```

Again, probably a fancier way to use `random.choice`, but I’m currently cooking breakfast and need to head off.